# Compile Error for list.where

Tags: c#, list, generics, where-clause

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error. Please help!!!

*'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
    public class HistTradePlot : Indicator
    {
        private class Traid
            {
                public DateTime Date { get; set; }
                public int Index { get; set; }
                public int Buy { get; set; }
                public int Price {get;set;}
            }
        List<Traid> traids = new List<Traid>();

            if (Bars.FirstBarOfSession)
                {Bars.Session.GetNextBeginEnd(BarsArray[0], 0, 
out sessionBegin, out sessionEnd);
                    var sessionTrades = traids.Where(t => t.Date > sessionBegin && t.Date <= sessionEnd);
                Print("Session Start: " + sessionBegin + " Session End: " + sessionEnd);
                for (int i=0;i<sessionTrades.Length();i++){
                Print(Convert.ToString(sessionTrades[i].Date));
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your file.

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when you haven't included the Linq namespace, so the compiler can't find the Linq extension methods like `Where`.  Try adding:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: And if that doesn't resolve the issue, make sure that your project has a reference to the `System.Core` assembly.

Answer (score 3):

Also, LINQ is in Frameworks 3.5 and later. If you are using a version of .NET that is before 3.5, LINQ isn't supported.